# How to pass data from a view to another

Tags: codeigniter, view, nested

I have the following problem:

I have a controller in which I have:

```
$this->load->model('girl_model');
$ragazze = $this->girl_model->get_girls();
$data['content'] = 'view_news';
$data['girls'] = $girls;
```

in my main view I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content">
        <?php $this->load->view($content,  array('girls' => $girls) ); ?>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copy Right 2015 
    </div>
</body>
```

In my subview I have:

```
<?php echo $girls ?>    
<?php foreach ($girls as $girl):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $girl; ?></td><br/>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

The problem is that I don't see the results of my query in the subview. I only see the Array word printed. It's like something is not passed correctly.
I'm new in CodeIgniter and I don't understand why it doesn't work.
Can you properly explain to me the solution?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you want to set `$data['girls'] = $ragazze;`?

Comment: var_dump($girls) on your subview and have a take a look at the structure obvously its a nested array (an array inside another array)

Comment: Hi, I hope my code will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI your code should be :

**controller :**

```
$this->load->model('girl_model');
$ragazze = $this->girl_model->get_girls();
$data['content'] = 'view_news';
$data['girls'] = $ragazze ;
//echo '<pre>';print_r($data) //debug here if you want
this->load->view('YourMainView',$data);
```

**Main View :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content">
        <?php $this->load->view($content,$girls); ?>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copy Right 2015 
    </div>
</body>
```

**In Sub View :**

```
<?php print_r($girls); ?>// $girls is an array you can not echo it you have to use print_r().
<?php foreach ($girls as $girl) ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $girl['field_name']; ?></td>//field name in your table.
        </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just load that $data in first view and it will that variable is automatically available in included view. in your case. please change according to written bellow.

```
 $this->load->model('girl_model');
 $ragazze = $this->girl_model->get_girls();
 $data['content'] = 'view_news';
 $data['girls'] = $ragazze;
```

load this data in this controller.

```
     $this->load->view('viewfilename',$data);
```

Now $girls is available for viewfilename.php and any view included in this viewfilename.php .

```
      <html>
      <head>
      <title> </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/assets/css/style.css">
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </div>

<div id="main-content">
    <?php $this->load->view($content); ?>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    Copy Right 2015 
</div>
```

now change it according to it and $girls will be available to $content views as well.